# android: Http post always gives the login page as response

Tags: android, apache, post, http-post

Hi i am sick and tired of this and cant find any solution on the web so here is my question. I am logging in to a website using Apache HTTP post. giving my credentials. But what ever i do no matter what code snippet i use from the net it always returns me the login page again in response. Here is my code please provide the solution.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "xxx"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxx"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            Log.i("Response num:", "" + response.getStatusLine().toString());

            Log.i("response page:", "" + responseHandler(response));

            Log.i("Headers:", "" + response.getHeaders("Location").toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
```

And the php script is:

```
<?php  

session_start();

include('Connectdb.php');



$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_accounts where username ='".$_POST["username"]."' AND password ='".$_POST["password"]."'");



if($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

  {

   $_SESSION['Suserid']=$row['hospital_id'];

 // mysql_close($con);

  if ($row['acc_type']=="patient"){
$_SESSION['verifiedUserType']="patient";



 header('Location:./home_P.php');
 }

 else

 if ($row['acc_type']=="admin"){

     $_SESSION['verifiedUserType']="admin";

 header('Location:./home_admin.php');}
 else
 if ($row['acc_type']=="doctor"){

     $_SESSION['verifiedUserType']="doctor";

 header('Location:./home_doc.php');}

 exit;

  }

else

{



mysql_close($con);



//session_start();


 header('Location:./index.php?failed=1');





}

?>
```

How can i get the page after the login and maintain session by grabing the cookie after user has logged in ?
p.s i get the http 1.1 200 OK status even if i give wrong username or password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement response handling in your application.
Here is a login credential snippet from my first application, it is quite similar to yours and it has worked for me.

```
    case R.id.login_login_but:
        Toast.makeText(this, "Logging in...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postLogin = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        postLogin.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_user", "User"));
        postLogin.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_pass", "Pass));

        try {
            String response = null;
            response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                    "http://giveaway.synamegames.com/appfiles/login.php", postLogin);
            String res = response.toString();
            res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            if (res.equals(1)) {
            // logged in
            } else {
            // incorrect user or password
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Server timeout please try again later. You must have internet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    break;
```

And the PHP script I used was...

```
<?php
$username=$_POST['post_user'];
$password=$_POST['post_pass'];
$user = 'db_user';
$pswd = 'db_password';
$db = 'db_name';
$server = 'www.domain.com';
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pswd);
mysql_select_db($db, $conn);
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users  WHERE  pass =('$password') AND user = $username")or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($query)==1) {
echo 1;
} else {
echo 0;
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

PS. If it worked please mark as correct :)

Comment: Hey try my code on this http://www.alinadental.site50.net/v2/sample_verify.php the username and pass is admin admin. Tell me if this works cuz it gives me bad username password in response.

Comment: On that page when i insert in admin//admin it gives me "successfully logged in" response. What i'd recommend you to do if its giving you a bad response in Android is to setup another php page specifically for android and use the php script i supplied and also changing the database specific variables to your database credentials.

Comment: Have you tried this site using your code? i know there must be a way "bad username " is an echo from the script i have changed the script now. I guess the problem occurs on the 

postLogin.add(new BasicNameValuePair("post_user", "User"));

what is the key? i mean what is "post_user"? as i see your code i guess its your php var. and "User" is your value.

Comment: i would mark your answer correct if my problem is solved by your code.

Comment: Sorry man cant give you the credentials i haven't made the database. What i want you to do is use this link and run the post given the user and pass and get the successful response.

Comment: Okay, so can you explain what you want in a more clear way then?

Comment: No problem, but just for the sake of completion could you tell me what got fixed?

Comment: You would laugh your ass off !! in the web it was GET instead of POST LOL

Answer (score 0):

after establishing the connection set some condition to chk whether name and password is null .

```
if(users != null && password != null){
            try{
                // send the name and password along with the url
                                // and authenticate the values.

            }catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

If already login done then next time this condition will automatically verified that and open the second page..

Comment: i dont think at all this will help

Answer (score 0):

You can get a List of cookies from your login request like this:

```
List<Cookie> cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

And to send the correct cookie back with a request use:

```
CookieStore store = new BasicCookieStore();
store.addCookie(yourCookie);
httpclient.setCookieStore(store);
```

---

I would advise you to use md5 to store you're password in the database. You should never save passwords in clear text. Maybe it is md5 and that's why it's not working?

Comment: dude what comes in (yourCookie) ?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I would guess a `Cookie` from the List you got from the Login (if only one cookie will be returned it'll be `cookies.get(0)`)